# Tile border around one piece shower

Tags: drywall, tile

I'm building a new addition and I have a 1 piece shower, I think maybe 80 inches tall.  I'm about to start putting up drywall in the bathroom.  If I want to put tile around the top and edges of the shower, do I just mount it on the purple drywall board, or should I put up concrete booard?

Answer (score 1):

At one time or another I've seen every type of drywall fail when it's used in a shower. Either because the grout cracked and went undetected, the soap dish leaked or water got behind the faucets. I'm a big fan of the concrete backer board. It's available in different thicknesses and many brands can be cut with a regular utility knife. Good luck